# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I am trying to run below code in Selenium web driver but its shows some error

The code is

```
    WebElement w=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='tab']"));

    JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor) driver;`

    js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('disable,'');",w);
```

The error is:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

(Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.115)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10240 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 463 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.3.1', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:04:52 -0800'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-AQGDP71', ip: '192.168.2.25', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233), userDataDir=C:\Users\SEKAR\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir3836_13558}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=59.0.3071.115, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
Session ID: 9568bb1918bcb9bfdfbc4afab2cf8294
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:638)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:540)
    at `enter code here`stepdefinition.Cheking`enter code here`.search_with_text_and_check_listed_corectly(Chek`enter code here`ing.ja`enter code here`va:57)
    at ?
```

When search with text and check listed corectly(Cheking.feature:7)

Comment: are we having an attribute disable for webelement w?

Answer (score 1):

you are missing quotes. may be a typo.

```
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('disable','');",w);
```

Comment: I tried but didn't work for me. Any other solution for that suggest me

Comment: Is it disable or disabled? Please change to disabled then try it

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing this issue, in my case I was using:

```
element.sendKeys("5'7");
```

If you have single quote in the data to be sent, **it needs to have back-slash before it.**
You can use following java code:

```
String text = "5'7";
text = text.replace("'", "\\'");
element.sendKeys(text);
```

Now, it will send the data as "5'7" instead of "5'7".

Answer (score 0):

the issue as Murthi said: you are missing quotes

incase you want to use selenium (python) with javascript to fill input with text from python it's better to use `json.dumps(python_str)`

and note json dumps add quotes so when you use the string in javascript do not put it between quotes

```
'test.innerText = "{}";'.format(json_dumps(python_str))
```

js will receive it like this: `'test.innerText = ""hello world"";` and you will see error sys :

> javascript error: Unexpected identifier hello
>
> if you used single quote you will have double quotes in string

so to solve this issue not add quotes single or double because `json.dumps` added already

```
"test.innerText = {};".format(json_dumps(python_str))
```

> and replace all qoutes with HTML entity codes

```
python_str = python_str.replace("'", "&apos;").replace('"', "&quot;").replace('`', '&#96;')
```